# Alphabetical order with nomenclature

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl, alphabet

Good evening everybody,

I am having a problem with the \nomencl package (with TeXstudio, the code is reported below).

I separated the nomenclature into "Acronyms", "Greek Letters", "Latin Letters", and "Superscripts and Subscripts". I wish every section would be alphabetically sorted, but this is not always the case. For instance, in the "Latin Letters" section, every time there is an arrow, a dot, or a tilde on top of the letter, this is not read by LateX as the actual letter, but as a different symbol (if I understood correctly from the documentation), which leads to a non-proper sorting of the letters: LateX sorts the dotted letters in alphabetical order among themselves, but not with respect to the other letters. The problem also holds for the "Greek Letters".

Could anyone be so kind to explain me how to fix the issue?

Thanks for your help and patience.

Riccardo

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

% Packages for the page layout
\usepackage[parts,floatperchapter,eulerchapternumbers,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm, heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}

% Nomenclature (Acronyms, greek letters and latin letters)
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{L}}{\item[\textbf{Latin Letters}]}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{\item[\textbf{Greek Letters}]}{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item[\textbf{Acronyms}]}{%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{P}}{\item[\textbf{Superscripts and Subscripts}]}{%
}}}}}


% To include International System units
\usepackage{siunitx}

% For the use of equations
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac} % To have more elegant fractions

% To insert the € symbol
\usepackage{eurosym}


\begin{document} 
    \frontmatter
    \nomenclature[A]{CEPCI}{Chemical Engineering Plant Cost Index [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{CFD}{Computational fluid dynamics [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{EtOH}{Ethanol [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{EU}{European Union [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{FCI}{Fixed capital investment [M\euro]}
    \nomenclature[A]{GHGs}{Greenhouse gases [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{GHSV}{Gas hourly space velocity [Nm\textsuperscript{3}/(m\textsuperscript{3}\textsubscript{CAT}$\cdot$h)]}
    \nomenclature[A]{KPIs}{Key performance indicators [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{LCOM}{Levelized cost of Methanol [\euro/t]}
    \nomenclature[A]{MeOH}{Methanol [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{NPV}{Net present value [M\euro]}
    \nomenclature[A]{RR}{Recycle ratio [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{rWGS}{Reverse water gas shift [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{WGS}{Water gas shift [-]}
    \mainmatter
    \nomenclature[L]{\sfrac{S}{C}}{Steam to methane ratio [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\dot{F}$}{Molar flow rate [mol/s]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\Delta$H$_\textup{ref}$}{Reforming reaction enthalpy [kJ/mol]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$T$}{Gas phase temperature  [K]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$p$}{Pressure  [bar]}
    \nomenclature[A]{PSA}{Pressure swing adsorpion  [bar]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$PF$$_\textup{ratio}$}{Product to feed ratio  [mol\textsubscript{MeOH} /mol\textsubscript{Feed}]}
    \nomenclature[A]{LCOH}{Levelized cost of H\textsubscript{2} [\euro/t]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$f$\textsubscript{i}}{i-th species fugacity [bar]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$K$\textsubscript{eq,MeOH}}{Methanol reaction equilibrium constant [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$K$\textsubscript{eq,rWGS}}{rWGS reaction equilibrium constant [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$K$\textsubscript{ads,1}}{Adsorption constant [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$K$\textsubscript{ads,2}}{Adsorption constant [1/bar\textsuperscript{0.5}]} 
    \nomenclature[L]{$K$\textsubscript{ads,3}}{Adsorption constant [1/bar]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$r$\textsubscript{MeOH}}{Methanol reaction rate [mol/(s$\cdot$kg\textsubscript{CAT})]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$r$\textsubscript{rWGS}}{rWGS reaction rate [mol/(s$\cdot$kg\textsubscript{CAT})]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\kappa$\textsubscript{i}}{Parameter derived from Arrhenius law (kinetic or adsorption constant) [Variable]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\widetilde{A}$\textsubscript{i}}{Generic pre-exponential factor [Variable]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\widetilde{B}$\textsubscript{i}}{Activation energy, adsorption enthalpy, or combination of these [J/mol]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\eta$\textsubscript{iso}}{Isentropic efficiency [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\eta$\textsubscript{mech}}{Mechanical efficiency [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{VLE}{Vapor-liquid equilibrium [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{EoS}{Equation of state [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{NRTL}{Non-random two-Liquid [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$R$}{Ideal gas constant [J/(mol K)]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$V\textsubscript{m}$}{Molar volume [m\textsuperscript{3}/mol]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$b$}{Characteristic constant [m\textsuperscript{3}/mol]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$a$}{Characteristic constant [Pa$\cdot$mol\textsuperscript{2}/m\textsuperscript{6}]}
    \nomenclature[P]{$i$}{Chemical species or plant unit [-]}
    \nomenclature[P]{$q$}{Chemical species [-]}
    \nomenclature[P]{$\star$}{Dimensionelss [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$x\textsubscript{q}$}{q-th component mole fraction [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$k\textsubscript{iq}$}{T-dependent parameter [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\widetilde{\omega}$\textsubscript{i}}{Acentric Pitxer's factor of species i [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$a$\textsubscript{i}}{$a$ coefficient of species i (Peng-Robinson) [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$a$\textsubscript{q}}{$a$ coefficient of species q (Peng-Robinson) [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$k\textsubscript{iq}\textsuperscript{(1,2,3)}$}{Binary interaction coefficients (Peng-Robinson) [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$b$\textsubscript{i}}{$b$ coefficient of species i (Peng-Robinson) [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$T$\textsubscript{crit}}{Critical temperature  [K]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$p$\textsubscript{crit}}{Critical pressure  [Pa]}
    \nomenclature[A]{ARD}{Absolute relative deviation [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$p\textsubscript{i}\textsuperscript{exp}$}{Experimental pressure  [bar]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$p\textsubscript{i}\textsuperscript{mod}$}{Model pressure  [bar]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$N\textsubscript{p}$}{Number of points  [bar]}
    \nomenclature[P]{$p$}{Points  [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{MDEA}{Methy dietahnolamine [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$C$\textsuperscript{0}\textsubscript{p,i}}{Reference cost  [\$]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$K$\textsubscript{1 2 3,i}}{Fitting parameters for the calculation of unit reference cost  [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$A$\textsubscript{i}}{Reference unit for reference cost estimation of unit i  [Variable (see Table \ref{Assumptions for FCI estimation})]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$F$\textsubscript{p, i}}{Pressure factor of unit i  [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$F$\textsubscript{p,vessel i}}{Pressure factor for vessels  [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$D$\textsubscript{i}}{Diameter of unit i  [m]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$p$\textsubscript{i}}{Operating pressure of unit i  [bar]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$C$\textsubscript{1 2 3,i}}{Constants for pressure factor calculation  [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$K$\textsubscript{1 2 3,ref}}{Fitting parameters for the calculation of reformer reference cost  [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$A$\textsubscript{ref}}{Reference unit for reformer reference cost estimation  [m\textsuperscript{3}/h]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$B$\textsubscript{1 2 3,i}}{Bare module factor for FCI estimation  [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$F$\textsubscript{M,i}}{Material factor of unit i [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$C$\textsubscript{BM, col i}}{Bare module cost of distillation columns [\$]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$F$\textsubscript{q, i}}{Factor to for the calculation of the distillation columns C\textsubscript{BM, col i} [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$N$\textsubscript{i}}{Number of trays [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{OFMSW}{Organic fraction of municipal solid waste [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{ISPRA}{Istituto superiore per la protezione e la ricerca ambientale [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{ARERA}{Autorità di regolazione per energia reti e ambiente [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{CAPEX}{Capital expenditures [M\euro]}
    \nomenclature[A]{OPEX}{Operating expenditures [M\euro]}
    \nomenclature[A]{CCF}{Capital charge factor [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{IGW}{Innovative Green World [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$C$\textsubscript{OL}}{Labour operating costs [M\euro/year]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$C$\textsubscript{UT}}{Operating Utility operating costs [M\euro/year]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$COM$\textsubscript{d}}{Cost of manufacture without depreciation [M\euro/year]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$R$\textsubscript{MeOH}}{Methanol selling price [\euro/t]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$CF$\textsubscript{k}}{Yearly cash flow [M\euro/year]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$C$\textsubscript{L}}{Cost of land purchasing [M\euro]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$t$\textsubscript{rate}}{Taxation rate [\%]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\alpha$}{Discount rate [\%]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$DCF$\textsubscript{k}}{Discounted cash flow [M\euro]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$N$\textsubscript{NP}}{Number of unit operations involving non-particulate matter [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$Y$\textsubscript{global}}{Global yield to methanol [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\eta$\textsubscript{Carbon}}{Carbon efficiency [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\eta$\textsubscript{Fuel}}{Fuel efficiency [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\dot{m}$\textsubscript{MeOH}}{Methanol mass flow rate [kg/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$B$\textsubscript{Biogas}}{Fraction of burned biogas [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\chi$\textsubscript{i}}{i-th species conversion [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$E$\textsubscript{CO\textsubscript{2}}}{{Emitted CO\textsubscript{2}} [kg\textsubscript{CO\textsubscript{2}emitted}/kg\textsubscript{CO\textsubscript{2}methanol}]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$N$\textsuperscript{$\circ$ Comp.\textsubscript{biogas}}}{Number of biogas component species [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$PBT$}{Payback time [years]}
    \nomenclature[A]{IRR}{Investment rate of return [\%]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$N$\textsubscript{op}}{Number of plant operating years [years]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$N$\textsubscript{op, actual}}{Number of actual plant operating years [years]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$N$\textsubscript{t}}{Number of tubes [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\varepsilon$}{Void fraction [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\dot{V}$\textsubscript{NORM,IN}}{Normal inlet volumetric flow rate [Nm\textsuperscript{3}/(h$\cdot$m\textsuperscript{3}\textsubscript{CAT})]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$D$\textsubscript{t}}{Tube diameter [m]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$L$\textsubscript{t}}{Tube length [m]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$N$\textsubscript{t}}{Tubes number [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$Pe$\textsubscript{M}}{Material Péclet number [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$Pe$\textsubscript{T}}{Thermal Péclet number [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$k$\textsubscript{eff,ax}}{Effective axial gas thermal conductivity [W/(m$\cdot$K)]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$h$\textsubscript{w}}{Wall heat transfer coefficient [W/(m\textsuperscript{2}$\cdot$K)]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$v$}{Gas superficial velocity [m/s]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\rho$\textsubscript{gas}}{Gas phase density [kg/m\textsuperscript{3}]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\mathcal{D}$\textsubscript{eff, ax H\textsubscript{2}}}{Effective axial thermal conducitivty of hydrogen [m/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$T$\textsubscript{cool}}{Cooling medium temperature [K]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$d$\textsubscript{pe}}{Diameter of a sphere with the same volumetric surface as the pellet [m]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$d$\textsubscript{p}}{Diameter of the pellet [m]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$k$\textsubscript{gas}}{Gas thermal conductivity [W/(m$\cdot$K)]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$k$\textsuperscript{$\circ$}\textsubscript{gas}}{Gas static thermal conductivity [W/(m$\cdot$K)]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$Pr$}{Prandtl number [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$Re$\textsubscript{d\textsubscript{pe}}}{Reynolds number, calculated with $d$\textsubscript{pe} [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$t$}{Time coordinate [s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$z$}{Axial coordinate [m]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$r$}{Radial coordinate [m]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$W$\textsubscript{t}}{Mass flow rate per unit area [kg/(s$\cdot$m\textsuperscript{2})]}
    \nomenclature[P]{$j$}{Chemical reaction [-]}
    \nomenclature[P]{$k$}{Discretization point on diffusion length [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\mathcal{D}$\textsubscript{eff, rad i}}{Effective radial diffusivity of i-th species [m/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$K$\textsubscript{m,i}}{Gas – solid mass transfer coefficient [m/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$a$\textsubscript{v}}{Catalyst pellet specific volumetric surface [m\textsuperscript{2}/m\textsuperscript{3}]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\omega$\textsubscript{i}}{Mass fraction of component i in the gas phase [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\omega$\textsubscript{s edge, i}}{Mass fraction of component i in the gas phase at the catalyst edge [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\rho$\textsubscript{cat}}{Catalyst density [kg\textsubscript{CAT}/m\textsuperscript{3}\textsubscript{CAT}]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$MM$\textsubscript{i}}{Molar mass of component i [kg/mol]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\nu$\textsubscript{ij}}{Stoichiometric coefficient of species i in reaction j [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$r$\textsubscript{j}}{Rate of j-th reaction [mol/(s$\cdot$kg\textsubscript{CAT})]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\bar{x}$}{Diffusion length coordinate [m]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$r$\textsubscript{jk}}{Rate of j-th reaction in k-th point of diffusion length  [mol/(s$\cdot$kg\textsubscript{CAT})]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\textup{NR}$}{Number of reactions [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\omega$\textsubscript{s, i}}{Mass fraction of component i in the gas phase inside catalyst [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\mathcal{D}$\textsubscript{eff, intr i}}{Effective intraparticle diffusion of i-th species [m/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$c$\textsubscript{p, gas}}{Specific heat at constant pressure [J/(kg$\cdot$K)]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$k$\textsubscript{eff,rad}}{Effective radial gas thermal conductivity [W/(m$\cdot$K)]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$h$\textsubscript{conv}}{Convective heat transfer coefficient [W/(m\textsuperscript{2}$\cdot$K)]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$T$\textsubscript{s}}{Solid phase temperature [K]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\Delta H$\textsubscript{r\textsubscript{j}}}{j-th reaction enthalpy [J/mol]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$MM$\textsubscript{gas}}{Gas molar mass [kg/mol]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$NC$}{Number of components [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$NR$}{Number of reactions [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$f$\textsubscript{m}}{Friction factor [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$D$\textsubscript{L}}{Diffusion length [m]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\omega$\textsubscript{i}\textsuperscript{IN N}}{Mass fraction of gas phase component i at the inlet section of the reactor (transient phase), when H\textsubscript{2} and CO\textsubscript{2} are inseted into the system [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\omega$\textsubscript{i}\textsuperscript{IN}}{Mass fraction of gas phase component i at the inlet section of the reactor, when H\textsubscript{2} is not present and CO\textsubscript{2} is vented [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\omega$\textsubscript{s,i}\textsuperscript{IN N}}{Mass fraction of gas phase component i inside the catalyst at the inlet section of the reactor (transient phase), when H\textsubscript{2} and CO\textsubscript{2} are inseted into the system [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\omega$\textsubscript{s,i}\textsuperscript{IN}}{Mass fraction of gas phase component i inside the catalyst at the inlet section of the reactor, when H\textsubscript{2} is not present and CO\textsubscript{2} is vented [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\mathcal{D}$\textsubscript{iq}}{Binary diffusion coefficient [m/\textsuperscript{2}s]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\Xi$\textsubscript{i}}{i-th species diffusion volume [m\textsuperscript{3}/mol]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$A$\textsubscript{c}}{Cross sectional area of the single tube [m\textsuperscript{2}]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\dot{m}$}{Mass flow rate going through the reactor [kg/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$Sh$\textsubscript{i}}{Sherwood number of species i [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$Sc$\textsubscript{i}}{Schmidt number of species i [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{BCs}{Boundary conditions [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\mu$\textsubscript{gas}}{Gas mixture viscosity [Pa$\cdot$s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$S$\textsubscript{p}}{Particle external surface [m\textsuperscript{2}]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$V$\textsubscript{p}}{Particle volume [m\textsuperscript{3}]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\varepsilon$\textsubscript{p}}{Pellet porosity [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\tau$}{Pellet tortuosity [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\mathcal{D}$\textsubscript{K,i}}{Knudsen diffusion coefficient of species i [m\textsuperscript{2}/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$r$\textsubscript{p}}{Mean pore radius [m]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$k$\textsubscript{cat}}{Catalyst thermal conductivity [W/(m$\cdot$K)]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$d$\textsubscript{pv}}{Diameter of a sphere with the same volume as the pellet [m]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$d$\textsubscript{pa}}{Diameter of a sphere with the same surface as the pellet [m]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$Re$\textsubscript{d\textsubscript{pa}}}{Reynolds number, calculated with $d$\textsubscript{pa} [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$Re$\textsubscript{d\textsubscript{pv}}}{Reynolds number, calculated with $d$\textsubscript{pv} [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$Nu$}{Nusselt number [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$h$\textsubscript{w, conv}}{Convective term of the wall heat transfer coefficient [W/(m\textsuperscript{2}$\cdot$K)]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\dot{F}$\textsubscript{rec}}{Mole flow rate of recycled gases to the methanol reactor [mol/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\dot{F}$\textsubscript{freh}}{Mole flow rate of fresh gases to the methanol reactor [mol/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\dot{F}$\textsubscript{syn, in}}{Mole flow rate of fresh syngas at methanol reactor entrance [mol/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\dot{F}$\textsubscript{CO\textsubscript{2}}}{Mole flow rate of carbon dioxide (vented or recycled) [mol/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\dot{F}$\textsubscript{H\textsubscript{2}}}{Mole flow rate of hydrogen (vented or recycled) [mol/s]}
    \nomenclature[A]{PDEs}{Partial Differential Equations  [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{OCFEM}{Orthogonal Collocation on Finite Elements Method  [-]}
    \nomenclature[A]{BFDM}{Backward Finite Differences Method  [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$T$\textsubscript{c}}{Centerline temperature [K]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$T$\textsubscript{w}}{Wall temperature [K]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$T$\textsubscript{av}}{Average temperature [K]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$z$\textsuperscript{$\star$}}{Dimensionless reactor length [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$T$\textsubscript{syngas}}{Syngas temperature [K]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$T$\textsubscript{max, 1D}}{Maximum temperature of the 1D model [K]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$T$\textsubscript{max, 2D}}{Maximum temperature of the 2D model [K]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$U$}{Global heat exchange coefficient [W/(m\textsuperscript{2}$\cdot$K)]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$d$$\dot{Q}$\textsubscript{tube}}{Infinitesimal heat released by the tube [kW]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$d$$\dot{F}$\textsubscript{CH\textsubscript{3}OH}}{Infinitesimal CH\textsubscript{3}OH mole flow rate per tube, flowing in the integration step  [mol/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$d$$\dot{F}$\textsubscript{CO}}{Infinitesimal CO mole flow rate per tube, flowing in the integration step  [mol/s]}
    \nomenclature[A]{POCS}{Periodic open cellular structures [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\overrightarrow{\textbf{v}}$}{Velocity Vector (CFD simulations) [m/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\widetilde{\overrightarrow{\textbf{v}}}$}{Favre averaged velocity vector (for CFD simulations) [m/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\overrightarrow{\textbf{J}}$\textsubscript{i}}{Material flux due to diffusion (CFD simulations) [kg/(m\textsuperscript{2}$\cdot$s)]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$E$\textsubscript{tot}}{Total energy [J/m\textsuperscript{3}]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\overrightarrow{\textbf{F}}$\textsubscript{b}}{Body forces (for CFD simulations) [N/m\textsuperscript{3}]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\mathcal{D}$\textsubscript{kin, i}}{Kinematic diffusion coefficient of species i (for CFD simulations)  [m\textsuperscript{2}/2]}
    \nomenclature[P]{$d$}{Generic spatial coordinate (for CFD simulations) [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\tilde{h}$\textsubscript{stat}}{Favre-averaged specific static enthalpy (for CFD simulations) [J/kg]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$v$\textsubscript{x}}{$x$ component of the velocity vector (for CFD simulations)  [m/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$v$\textsubscript{y}}{$y$ component of the velocity vector (for CFD simulations)  [m/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$v$\textsubscript{z}}{$z$ component of the velocity vector (for CFD simulations)  [m/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$S$\textsubscript{M\textsubscript{x}}}{$x$ component of the momentum source (for CFD simulations)  [N/m\textsuperscript{3}]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$S$\textsubscript{M\textsubscript{y}}}{$y$ component of the momentum source (for CFD simulations)  [N/m\textsuperscript{3}]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$S$\textsubscript{M\textsubscript{z}}}{$z$ component of the momentum source (for CFD simulations)  [N/m\textsuperscript{3}]}
    \nomenclature[P]{$\widetilde{}$}{Densitiy weighetd or Favre-averaged parameter (for CFD simulations) [-]}
    \nomenclature[P]{$\bar{}$}{Time-averaged parameter [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$k$}{Turbulent kinetic energy epr unit mass [J/kg]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\delta$\textsubscript{ij}}{Kronecker delta  [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\mu$\textsubscript{t}}{Turbulent (or Eddy) viscosity  [Pa$\cdot$s]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\Gamma$\textsubscript{t}}{Turbulent (or Eddy) diffusivity  [m/s]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\sigma$\textsubscript{t}}{Turbulent Prandtl number  [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$C$\textsubscript{$\mu$}}{Dimensionless constant  [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\epsilon$}{Rate of viscous dissipation (for CFD calculations) [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$S$\textsubscript{h}}{Energy source (CFD calculations) [W/m\textsuperscript{3}]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$q$\textsubscript{w}}{Wall heat flux [W/m\textsuperscript{2}]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$u$\textsuperscript{$\star$}}{Alternative velocity scale (for CFD computations)  [m/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$Pr$}{Prandtl number (for CFD computations) [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\Gamma$}{Function of $Pr$ number (for CFD computations) [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$y$\textsuperscript{$\star$}}{Dimensionless distance from the wall (for CFD computations) [-]}
    \nomenclature[P]{$\dot{}$}{Per unit time [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\chi$\textsubscript{CO\textsubscript{2}}}{Carbon dioxide conversion (Portha's definition) [-]}
    \nomenclature[G]{$\chi$\textsubscript{H\textsubscript{2}}}{Hydrogen conversion (Portha's definition) [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$S$\textsubscript{MeOH}}{Methanol selectivity (Portha's definition) [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$x$\textsubscript{CO, in}}{Inlet CO mole fraction (CFD validation) [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$x$\textsubscript{CO\textsubscript{2}, in}}{Inlet CO\textsubscript{2} mole fraction (CFD validation) [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$x$\textsubscript{H\textsubscript{2}, in}}{Inlet H\textsubscript{2} mole fraction (CFD validation) [-]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$m$\textsubscript{CAT}}{Catalyst mass [kg]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$\dot{F}$\textsubscript{in}}{Inlet molar flow rate [mol/s]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$L$\textsubscript{reac}}{Reactor length [m]}
    \nomenclature[L]{$V$\textsubscript{pillow}}{Pillow-plate reactor volume [m\textsuperscript{3}]}
    \printnomenclature[5cm]
    \backmatter 
\end{document}
```